# React application build can't load SVGs as Components, but it works on development

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm importing my SVGs in the following way:
`import { ReactComponent as Calendar } from './svg/action/calendar.svg';`

But, in the build files, it looks like this:
`var _calendar = require("./svg/action/calendar.svg");`

The first, in development, returns in the Calendar constant a react object. The following does return a path to be used as a src of an image.

My build config looks like this:
`"build-lib": "rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,*.mdx,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__",`

I know that I can create a .js file with the SVG code there, but I want to avoid it.

Thanks!

I know that it is possible to use SVGs in React like that, so I think it is a build problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your svg's as images you need a proper loader, but you can extract the svg info and create your own component, like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Logo = () => (
  <div className="logo">
    <svg width="124px" height="34px" viewBox="0 0 124 34" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <g id="Preview" stroke="none" strokeWidth={1} fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <g id="Navbar-Copy" transform="translate(-1.000000, -3.000000)">
          <g id="Logotype">
            <g id="Text" transform="translate(38.031915, 4.000000)">
              <path id="SVGText" d="M7.94814815,4.48 L9.73540741,4.48 L9.73540741,14.0373333 L7.94814815,14.0373333 L7.94814815,4.48 Z M21.1738667,14.0373333 L21.1601185,7.70218667 L17.9980444,12.9450667 L17.2006519,12.9450667 L14.0385778,7.78410667 L14.0385778,14.0373333 L12.3338074,14.0373333 L12.3338074,4.48 L13.8048593,4.48 L17.6268444,10.8151467 L21.3800889,4.48 L22.8511407,4.48 L22.8648889,14.0373333 L21.1738667,14.0373333 Z M29.4227556,4.48 C30.256814,4.48 30.9831673,4.61653197 31.601837,4.8896 C32.2205068,5.16266803 32.6948132,5.55405967 33.0247704,6.06378667 C33.3547276,6.57351366 33.5197037,7.17880538 33.5197037,7.87968 C33.5197037,8.57145235 33.3547276,9.17446854 33.0247704,9.68874667 C32.6948132,10.2030248 32.2205068,10.596692 31.601837,10.86976 C30.9831673,11.142828 30.256814,11.27936 29.4227556,11.27936 L27.2505481,11.27936 L27.2505481,14.0373333 L25.4632889,14.0373333 L25.4632889,4.48 L29.4227556,4.48 Z M29.3402667,9.77749333 C30.1193323,9.77749333 30.7104967,9.61365497 31.1137778,9.28597333 C31.5170588,8.95829169 31.7186963,8.48953194 31.7186963,7.87968 C31.7186963,7.26982806 31.5170588,6.80106831 31.1137778,6.47338667 C30.7104967,6.14570503 30.1193323,5.98186667 29.3402667,5.98186667 L27.2505481,5.98186667 L27.2505481,9.77749333 L29.3402667,9.77749333 Z M35.4444444,4.48 L37.2317037,4.48 L37.2317037,12.5354667 L42.2635259,12.5354667 L42.2635259,14.0373333 L35.4444444,14.0373333 L35.4444444,4.48 Z M49.9212444,11.8254933 L45.1093926,11.8254933 L44.1607704,14.0373333 L42.3185185,14.0373333 L46.6491852,4.48 L48.4089481,4.48 L52.753363,14.0373333 L50.8836148,14.0373333 L49.9212444,11.8254933 Z M49.3300741,10.4328533 L47.5153185,6.25493333 L45.7143111,10.4328533 L49.3300741,10.4328533 Z M62.5282963,4.48 L62.5282963,14.0373333 L61.0572444,14.0373333 L55.7504593,7.56565333 L55.7504593,14.0373333 L53.9769481,14.0373333 L53.9769481,4.48 L55.448,4.48 L60.7547852,10.95168 L60.7547852,4.48 L62.5282963,4.48 Z" fill="#000000" fillRule="evenodd" />
              <path id="SVGIMPLAN" d="M14.2448,27.904 L12.2788148,25.1050667 C12.1963255,25.1141689 12.0725934,25.11872 11.9076148,25.11872 L9.73540741,25.11872 L9.73540741,27.904 L7.94814815,27.904 L7.94814815,18.3466667 L11.9076148,18.3466667 C12.7416733,18.3466667 13.4680265,18.4831986 14.0866963,18.7562667 C14.7053661,19.0293347 15.1796724,19.4207263 15.5096296,19.9304533 C15.8395868,20.4401803 16.004563,21.0454721 16.004563,21.7463467 C16.004563,22.4654258 15.8281302,23.0843707 15.4752593,23.6032 C15.1223884,24.1220293 14.6160033,24.5088698 13.9560889,24.7637333 L16.1695407,27.904 L14.2448,27.904 Z M14.2035556,21.7463467 C14.2035556,21.1364947 14.0019181,20.667735 13.598637,20.3400533 C13.195356,20.0123717 12.6041915,19.8485333 11.8251259,19.8485333 L9.73540741,19.8485333 L9.73540741,23.6578133 L11.8251259,23.6578133 C12.6041915,23.6578133 13.195356,23.4916994 13.598637,23.1594667 C14.0019181,22.8272339 14.2035556,22.3561986 14.2035556,21.7463467 Z M22.1499852,24.5316267 L22.1499852,27.904 L20.3627259,27.904 L20.3627259,24.5589333 L16.5819852,18.3466667 L18.4929778,18.3466667 L21.3113481,23.0024533 L24.1572148,18.3466667 L25.9169778,18.3466667 L22.1499852,24.5316267 Z M33.3822222,27.904 L31.416237,25.1050667 C31.3337477,25.1141689 31.2100156,25.11872 31.045037,25.11872 L28.8728296,25.11872 L28.8728296,27.904 L27.0855704,27.904 L27.0855704,18.3466667 L31.045037,18.3466667 C31.8790955,18.3466667 32.6054488,18.4831986 33.2241185,18.7562667 C33.8427883,19.0293347 34.3170946,19.4207263 34.6470519,19.9304533 C34.9770091,20.4401803 35.1419852,21.0454721 35.1419852,21.7463467 C35.1419852,22.4654258 34.9655524,23.0843707 34.6126815,23.6032 C34.2598106,24.1220293 33.7534255,24.5088698 33.0935111,24.7637333 L35.306963,27.904 L33.3822222,27.904 Z M33.3409778,21.7463467 C33.3409778,21.1364947 33.1393403,20.667735 32.7360593,20.3400533 C32.3327782,20.0123717 31.7416138,19.8485333 30.9625481,19.8485333 L28.8728296,19.8485333 L28.8728296,23.6578133 L30.9625481,23.6578133 C31.7416138,23.6578133 32.3327782,23.4916994 32.7360593,23.1594667 C33.1393403,22.8272339 33.3409778,22.3561986 33.3409778,21.7463467 Z M44.3532444,26.4157867 L44.3532444,27.904 L37.1354667,27.904 L37.1354667,18.3466667 L44.1607704,18.3466667 L44.1607704,19.83488 L38.9227259,19.83488 L38.9227259,22.3197867 L43.5696,22.3197867 L43.5696,23.7806933 L38.9227259,23.7806933 L38.9227259,26.4157867 L44.3532444,26.4157867 Z M64.2055704,18.3466667 L61.016,27.904 L59.1187556,27.904 L56.7403259,20.8315733 L54.3206519,27.904 L52.4096593,27.904 L49.2200889,18.3466667 L51.0760889,18.3466667 L53.4682667,25.61024 L55.9566815,18.3466667 L57.6064593,18.3466667 L60.0398815,25.6512 L62.5008,18.3466667 L64.2055704,18.3466667 Z M73.0868741,26.4157867 L73.0868741,27.904 L65.8690963,27.904 L65.8690963,18.3466667 L72.8944,18.3466667 L72.8944,19.83488 L67.6563556,19.83488 L67.6563556,22.3197867 L72.3032296,22.3197867 L72.3032296,23.7806933 L67.6563556,23.7806933 L67.6563556,26.4157867 L73.0868741,26.4157867 Z M81.899437,22.9341867 C82.4310348,23.1071298 82.8526404,23.3961224 83.1642667,23.8011733 C83.4758929,24.2062242 83.6317037,24.709117 83.6317037,25.3098667 C83.6317037,26.138173 83.3109168,26.7775977 82.6693333,27.22816 C82.0277499,27.6787223 81.0928852,27.904 79.8647111,27.904 L75.0803556,27.904 L75.0803556,18.3466667 L79.5897481,18.3466667 C80.7262674,18.3466667 81.6015574,18.5673933 82.2156444,19.0088533 C82.8297315,19.4503133 83.1367704,20.0578806 83.1367704,20.8315733 C83.1367704,21.3048913 83.0267863,21.7235893 82.8068148,22.08768 C82.5868433,22.4517707 82.2843871,22.7339368 81.899437,22.9341867 Z M76.8676148,19.7393067 L76.8676148,22.3744 L79.3972741,22.3744 C80.0205266,22.3744 80.4994156,22.2628989 80.8339556,22.0398933 C81.1684955,21.8168878 81.335763,21.4914866 81.335763,21.06368 C81.335763,20.6267711 81.1684955,20.2968189 80.8339556,20.0738133 C80.4994156,19.8508078 80.0205266,19.7393067 79.3972741,19.7393067 L76.8676148,19.7393067 Z M79.7547259,26.51136 C81.1387131,26.51136 81.8306963,26.0517024 81.8306963,25.1323733 C81.8306963,24.2130443 81.1387131,23.7533867 79.7547259,23.7533867 L76.8676148,23.7533867 L76.8676148,26.51136 L79.7547259,26.51136 Z" fill="#3D5AFE" fillRule="evenodd" />
              <rect fill="#000000" fillRule="nonzero" x="67.6666667" y="8.53333333" width="19.1985055" height="1.57144959" />
            </g>
            <g id="Logo" transform="translate(0.000000, 3.466667)" fill="#3D5AFE" fillRule="nonzero">
              <path d="M1.7831477,9.59049324 L16.0556844,17.3500842 C16.196533,17.4267474 16.3516707,17.4650142 16.5068083,17.4650142 C16.661946,17.4650142 16.8170836,17.4267474 16.9579323,17.3500842 L31.230469,9.59049324 C31.5417649,9.42121147 31.7361973,9.09146875 31.7361973,8.73253951 C31.7361973,8.37361027 31.5418925,8.04386754 31.230469,7.87458578 L16.9579323,0.114994857 C16.6761074,-0.038331619 16.3375093,-0.038331619 16.0556844,0.114994857 L1.7831477,7.87458578 C1.47185174,8.04386754 1.27741935,8.37361027 1.27741935,8.73253951 C1.27741935,9.09146875 1.47185174,9.42121147 1.7831477,9.59049324 Z M16.5068083,2.07619874 L28.7501802,8.73253951 L16.5068083,15.3888803 L4.26343647,8.73253951 L16.5068083,2.07619874 Z M31.230469,15.6373614 C31.5418925,15.8066432 31.7361973,16.1363859 31.7361973,16.4953152 C31.7361973,16.8542444 31.5417649,17.1839871 31.230469,17.3532689 L16.9579323,25.1128598 C16.8170836,25.1895231 16.661946,25.2277898 16.5068083,25.2277898 C16.3516707,25.2277898 16.196533,25.1895231 16.0556844,25.1128598 L1.7831477,17.3532689 C1.47172416,17.1839871 1.27741935,16.8542444 1.27741935,16.4953152 C1.27741935,16.1363859 1.47185174,15.8066432 1.7831477,15.6373614 L5.97377808,13.3591272 C6.43970137,13.1057882 7.01955387,13.2845394 7.26871821,13.7582689 C7.51788255,14.2319985 7.34207689,14.821566 6.87602602,15.0749049 L4.26343647,16.4953152 L16.5068083,23.1515262 L28.7501802,16.4951854 L26.167572,15.0911196 C25.7015212,14.8377807 25.5257155,14.2483429 25.7748798,13.7744837 C26.0240442,13.3007541 26.6037691,13.1218733 27.06982,13.3753419 L31.230469,15.6373614 Z M31.230469,23.4094419 C31.5418925,23.5787237 31.7361973,23.9085961 31.7361973,24.2675254 C31.7361973,24.6264546 31.5417649,24.9561973 31.230469,25.1254791 L16.9579323,32.88507 C16.8170836,32.9617332 16.661946,33 16.5068083,33 C16.3516707,33 16.196533,32.9617332 16.0556844,32.88507 L1.7831477,25.1254791 C1.47172416,24.9561973 1.27741935,24.6264546 1.27741935,24.2675254 C1.27741935,23.9085961 1.47185174,23.5788534 1.7831477,23.4095716 L5.78534197,21.2336847 C6.25126525,20.9802161 6.83111776,21.159097 7.0802821,21.6328265 C7.32944644,22.106556 7.15364077,22.6961235 6.68758991,22.9494625 L4.26343647,24.2673956 L16.5068083,30.9236067 L28.7501802,24.2672659 L26.2994901,22.9349341 C25.8334392,22.6815952 25.6576335,22.0921573 25.9067979,21.6182981 C26.1559622,21.1445686 26.7355596,20.9658174 27.201738,21.2191563 L31.230469,23.4094419 Z" id="Shape" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
);

export default Logo;
```

you can use [this page](https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm) to transform regular html to jsx.